# Importing text files to excel - Start a new row everytime a word is encountered

Tags: excel, vba

I have a number of text files that I want to import into excel. I want my macro to open a file and when it encounters the word 'PRICE' it places that line in A1. Each line after that will be placed in b1, c1 etc. When the word PRICE is found again, a new row is started and that line is placed in a2 followed by lines in b2, c2 etc. I think I should use Instr. The code below seems to place the lines with PRiCE in new rows but the following lines in the text files don't seem to follow. I think I just need a minor adjustment within the DO while not loop .Any help would be great!

```
x = 1 'to offset rows for each file

' Loop thru all files in the folder
For Each file In folder.Files

' set the starting point to write the data to
Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1)

' Open the file
Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)



i = 0 'to offset columsn for each line
' Read the file one line at a time
Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream

    TextLine = FileText.ReadLine 'read line

    If InStr(TextLine, "FINEX") > 0 Then 'find text

    x = x + 1
    Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1)
    cl.Offset(, 0).Value = TextLine
    'i = i + 1
    'cl.Value = TextLine

    'MsgBox ("yes")
    Else
     cl.Offset(, i).Value = TextLine 'fill cell
    i = i + 1
    End If
Loop

' Clean up
FileText.Close

x = x + 1

Next file
```

Comment: you say `Price` in your explanation, but `FINEX` in your code... which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I helped you with this code yesterday and happened to see, I thought I would take stab:

See if the code below gets it for you. If not, let me know and I can tweak it:

```
    x = 1 'to offset rows for each file and at price

' Loop thru all files in the folder
For Each file In folder.Files

    ' set the starting point to write the data to
    Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1)

    ' Open the file
    Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

    i = 1 'to offset columsn for each line

    ' Read the file one line at a time
    Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream

        TextLine = FileText.ReadLine 'read line

        If InStr(TextLine, "PRICE") > 0 Then 'find text

            cl.Offset(x - 1, 0).Value = TextLine
            x = x + 1

        Else

            cl.Offset(x - 1, i).Value = TextLine 'fill cell
            i = i + 1

        End If

    Loop

Next
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. That started a new row when the word 'Price' came up. Unfortunately, the lines that followed the PRICE line in the original text file where not placed in the columns b,c,d etc. Instead if they were in line 26 of the original text file they were placed in column Z. I used an old macro that I had to delete the unwanted blank cells but that still leaves a few remaining. Removing them is my next task. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents

```
Dim f As File, fileStream As TextStream, filetext As String, NewLines() As String, Offset As Long

Offset = 1

Set fileStream = f.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)
filetext = fileStream.ReadAll

filetext = Replace(filetext, vbCrLf, " ") 'make everything one line
NewLines = Split(filetext, "PRICE") 'make a new set of lines based on PRICE

For l = LBound(NewLines) To UBound(NewLines)

    ActiveSheet.Cells(l + Offset, 1) = NewLines(l)
Next l

fileStream.Close
Set fileStream = Nothing
```

Comment: Hi Brad. I'm sure your code worked great but I seemed to have difficulty incorporating it into my existing code. Thanks though